# Dealing with out-of-scope variable against an AJAX call

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have the following code:

```
var User = {
  get: function (options) {
    var self = this;

    $.ajax({
      url: options.url,
      success: function (data, response) {
        self.nextPageUrl = data.pagination.next_page;
        options.success(data, response);
      }
    });
  },
  nextPage: function (success) {
    this.get({
      url: this.nextPageUrl, 
      success: success
    });
  }
}

User.get({
  url: 'https://cache.getchute.com/v2/albums/aus6kwrg/assets',
  success: function (data, response) {
    // Through `data.pagination.next_page` I can get the URL
    // of the next page.
  }
});

User.nextPage({
  success: function (data, response) {
    // Here I want to make the same request but using the next_page
    // based on the next related to the previous' one.
  }
});
```

### The problem

Basically, I want to perform the `nextPage()` operation based on the antecessor request (`User.get()`), but due to its asynchronousity, the `nextPage()` method doesn't know the `this.nextPageUrl` property—it returns `undefined` as expected.

Finally, the question is: can someone think in a way to keep the current syntax flow but solving this approach? Actually, is there a way?

*And no, I'm not available to make a synchronous request.*

#### General knowledge

I thought to use an event mechanism to deal with this: when the request is made and `.nextPage()` is called, then try to listen to an event to be emitted for **x seconds**, then I expected the `this.nextPageUrl` property to be available in that event-based scope.

What do you guys think?

**DISCLAIMER:** The logic of `next_page` is preprocessed by the server and only then is sent to the client. I have no option to use an increment/decrement behavioral operation.

---

If you want to play with this problem, [click here for the jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LygL512v/1/).

Comment: Have `get` return a promise and call `nextPage` with the result. In fact, if you just `return` that `$.ajax` request, that's a promise.

Comment: Why `-1`? I _really_ want to understand—is the question's quality bad?

Comment: I think the problem lies in `this.nextPageUrl`. `this` isn't pointing to User. If you use `User.nextPageUrl` you will be able to access it outside the scope of the callback.

Comment: +1 @GuilhermeOderdenge - I think you asked a well scoped question with an easily reproduceable fiddle. I wish more questions were like this. Please do not remove it or be discouraged by a drive by down vote. This may be a frequently encountered problem, but this is a well articulated version of it.

Comment: @LimH. It isn't a scope problem. My bad leaving that behind.

Comment: @GuilhermeOderdenge hey I just want to clarify. You want to defer User.nextPage until the ajax request User.get is finished, is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***[`jsFiddle Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/mq1hhsws/)***

There are a couple of options. You could bind the setter of the property to also call the `nextPage`, you could poll from calling `nextPage` every n milliseconds until the nextPageUrl property was populated, you could use a promise, you could use a nextPageQueue.

I think that a queue may be the simplest form of completing this. I also think it may be useful to have User store some local variables in this situation, and that the use of a function object may be more inline with that.

It would look like this

```
var User = new function(){
  var pageQueue = [];
  var get = this.get = function (options) {
    $.ajax({
      url: options.url,
      dataType: 'JSON',
      success: function (data, response) {
        options.success(data, response);
        var nextPageUrl = data.pagination.next_page;
        if( pageQueue.length > 0 ){
         pageQueue[0](nextPageUrl);
         pageQueue.splice(0,1);
        }
      }
    });
  };
  var nextPage = this.nextPage = function (options) {
    pageQueue.push(function(nextPageUrl){
      get({
        url: nextPageUrl,
        success: options.success
      });
    });
  };
};
```

and your calls would not change.

```
User.get({
  url: 'https://cache.getchute.com/v2/albums/aus6kwrg/assets',
  success: function (data, response) {
    // Through `data.pagination.next_page` I can get the URL
    // of the next page.
      console.log('get');
      console.log(data);
      console.log(response);
  }
});

User.nextPage({
  success: function (data, response) {
    // Here I want to make the same request but using the next_page
    // based on the next related to the previous' one.
    console.log('next');
    console.log(data);
    console.log(response);
  }
});
```

Comment: Man, it worked like a charm! Thank you very much! But I didn't understand what you did exactly—can you explain a little more? Like, how does `pageQueue.push(function (nextPageUrl(){});` know the `nextPageUrl`? I can't figure out how this happened.

Comment: @GuilhermeOderdenge - That pushes a function into an array which has a single argument of nextPageUrl. This means that it expects to be called with a variable passed in for the value of nextPageUrl. Inside of the get function, if the queue is not empty, it calls the first function in the queue, providing the value of data.pagination.next_page which will be accepted in the function first pushed as the value of nextPageUrl.

Answer (score 1):

You can grab a reference to your User object before making the asynchronous request.

```
var User = {
    get: function (options) {
    var self = this;
    $.ajax({
        url: options.url,
        success: function (data, response) {
          self.nextPageUrl = data.pagination.next_page;
          options.success(data, response);
        }
    });
},
```

Comment: I wouldn't use `self` though. Then you would have to type `window.self` instead of simply `self` because `window` is implicit and you overwrite the possibility off it belonging to the `window` Object implicitly.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your get method and eliminate your nextPage method entirely:

```
var User = {
  url: 'https://cache.getchute.com/v2/albums/aus6kwrg/assets',
  get: function (options) {
    var self = this;

    self.pageXhr = $.ajax({
      url: self.nextPageUrl ? self.nextPageUrl : self.url,
      dataType: 'JSON',
      success: function (data, response) {
        self.nextPageUrl = data.pagination.next_page;
        self.pageXhr = false;
        options.success(data, response);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Then whenever you call User.get, it will either call the current page or the next page. I am not sure about the context of when you want to get the subsequent pages, but if you need the requests to be queued you can wait for the existing request to finish before triggering the next request. For example:

```
if (self.pageXhr) {
   self.pageXhr = self.pageXhr.then(function() {
      return $.ajax({
          url: self.nextPageUrl ? self.nextPageUrl : self.url,
          dataType: 'JSON',
          success: function (data, response) {
            self.nextPageUrl = data.pagination.next_page;
            options.success(data, response);
          }
      });
   });
}
```